How can the Jewish burden of proof argument against Christianity be refuted?
Adherents of Rabbinic Judaism makes the following argument:

If Christianity is not true then it is idolatry because we know that Jesus was at least human.  The abrogation of the Mosaic Law although not strictly impossible due to the ambiguity of phrases such as "l- your generations" and "3ôlām" would seem to require a high level of proof.

Therefore, if Rabbinic Judaism is not logically contradictory then it is true.



The question begins with 'If Christianity is not true ...'. The question needs to substantiate this statement before proceeding further.

If it cannot be substantiated, as you say, and if there is no argument, as you say, then the question is moot.

Huh? Those three points do not logically connect with each other.

Premise 1 - OK, fair enough. Premise 2 - dubious, as noted by SLM. The conclusion though is simply a non sequitur, it doesn't in any way follow from the premises as stated.

Logically, how is "3." different from concluding: "Therefore if Pastafarianism is not logically contradictory then it is true."?

Christianity is not a branch off from Rabbinic Judaism. Rabbinic Judaism evolved out of the Pharisaical school of thought in response to the destruction of the Temple in 70AD and thus, any argument which presumes Rabbinic Judaism to be the default and that Christianity is an addition, is begging the question. Both grew out of competing traditions within 1st century Judaism. The Rabbinic claim that they are more faithful to pre-Jesus Judaism requires proof.

If you accept the premise that the Pharisees were the only legitimate form of Judaism at that time, then you should not expect to be able to build a coherent case for Christianity over against Rabbinic Judaism.

Rabbinic Judaism is certainly not "more or less the same" as pre-70AD Judaism. Most obviously, the Jews had to work out how to conduct Judaism without a temple or sacrifices. That's a huge change. Also, it seems pretty well-accepted that pre-Christian Judaism had much more emphasis on messianic expectations than Rabbinic Judaism has now, which may be due to Rabbinic Judaism deliberately putting ground between themselves and Christianity, or for other reasons.

Also, it appears inconsistent to assert both the authority of the Sanhedrin and that the Pharisees were the only non-heretical sect of Judaism, as the Sanhedrin also had members from the Sadducees, perhaps was even dominated by Sadducees prior to the destruction of the temple.

You've reduced the 3 points to 2 points, but I still don't have the slightest idea how point 1 relates to the "therefore" in point 2.


OP: Christianity was unanimously condemned by the Sanhedrin.

The one in 425AD, the one recently, or the one prior to 70AD?
After all, this OP statement is verifiably false on its face.  Thus, the whole from the part fails, falling into the maelstrom of history.
Joseph of Arimethea stood against the Council/Sanhedrin.

(The same had not consented to the counsel and deed of them;) he was of Arimathaea, a city of the Jews: who also himself waited for the kingdom of God. Lk 23:51

As did Nicodemus who was also a member of the Council.

And there came also Nicodemus, which at the first came to Jesus by night, and brought a mixture of myrrh and aloes, about an hundred pound weight. Jn 13:39

So no, Christianity was not universally condemned by the Sanhedrin.
Just so you know, the Council was ready to leave Jesus' dead body on the ground as a curse to them (Jn 19:31, Deut 21:23 - you can figure it out).  Thankful, the decision was not unanimous.  Some who know better should be repenting.

Neither is there salvation in any other: for there is none other name under heaven given among men, whereby we must be saved. Acts 4:2

Some should be rejoicing that the Council unanimously did not condemn the Messiah.

OP: Therefore, if Rabbinic Judaism is not logically contradictory then it is true.

Rabbinic Judaism is contradictory as shown, plus in myriads of other places.  Thus, false it is.
Good luck.

Of course. ... ...

You made the argument in your OP.  "Christianity was unanimously condemned by the Sanhedrin. (cf. Dt. 17:11).  Therefore, if Rabbinic Judaism is not logically contradictory then it is true."  I've shown Christianity was not unanimously condemned.  So, your conclusion would be it is false.  The context gives you the answer.  Now, if you want to say, for any other reason, that you believe RJ is true, then go right ahead.

The Sanhedrin did reject Christianity.  Not sure your point (if it is the same or changed).  As to NT being true, the same argument may be made about the OT.  But if we assume the OT is true with its foretelling of Messiah, then the question is simply whether Jesus Christ fulfilled the requirements, including the suffering servant and king of kings motifs, and perhaps most importantly including the time (see Daniel's 70 weeks).  If not Christ, the time factor allows no one else to fulfill it.
